# How to handle menu opening on clicking of an anchor text through selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Clicking on the anchor tag opens a menu and in one of the options(named Application) there is another menu where few applications are listed and I have to click on them. I am unable to click on it since it is not wrapped in a select tag. 
here is the code:

```
<div class="menuBarSub mb_standardSub" menu="mn-1441711622465-/contextMenu" style="position: absolute; left: 1252.33px; top: 17px; display: block; z-index: 100;" role="navigation">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody role="menu" style="width: 100%;">
<tr id="/contextMenu/ID1277705525089001" class="menuItem" orientation="vertical">
<tr id="/contextMenu/ID1285350191126000" class="menuItem" orientation="vertical">
<tr id="/contextMenu/ID1412292365029000" class="menuItem" orientation="vertical">
<tr id="/contextMenu/ID1416325132235000" class="menuItem selected" orientation="vertical" aria-selected="true">
<tr id="/contextMenu/ID1332408920353004" class="menuItem" orientation="vertical">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few points:
1. After clicking on the anchor tag you will have to wait for the presence of the menu. Use `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions` class for that.
2. You will have to hover over the menu appearing using `Actions` class `clickAndHold(Locator).build().perform()` method.
3. The get(0) is a different issue and just so that you should know it has nothing to do with selenium but has to do with Java. get(0) is method from `List<E>` collections Interface which is returned by `WebDriver#findElements(Locator)` API.
Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I am not able to use clickandhold, it does nothing.

Comment: you will have to use clickAndHold(Locator).build().perform(); i hope you are trying using that, if not try mouseOver(Locator).build().perform()

Comment: Here's what I did, I clicked on the menu, gave thread.sleep then used move to element to the first menu option which worked. But under the menu options the child options open to the left, these options are not accessible

Comment: do you have a public url depicting your issue..i can paste sample code for you then?

Comment: I do not have a public URL for that, the UI is developed in Pega.

Comment: please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36146925/automate-axis-bank-website/36147210#36147210 This does something similar to what u want just change the locators