# Automate axis bank website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Hi i want to select saving accounts using the following sequence and code . The script is passing every time but saving accounts in not clicked at all.
1. Open axis bank website. 2. Open Products dropdown 3. Open Accounts section in it 4. Click Savings account 5. Open Current Accounts section on next page

```
driver.get("http://www.axisbank.com/");
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
WebElement prod=driver.findElement(By.id("product"));
WebElement saving=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul[2]/ul/li[1]/a"));
WebElement account=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a"));
action.moveToElement(prod).moveToElement(account).moveToElement(saving).click();
Action composite=action.build();
composite.perform();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
//This is just to wait for that mobile window to go..You can add some other logic for that to disappear
            Thread.sleep(15000);
            WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 15,3000);
            WebElement prod=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Products']")));
            WebElement saving=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[starts-with(@title,'Savings Accounts')]"));
            WebElement account=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Accounts']"));
            action.click(prod).perform();
            action.moveToElement(account).perform();
            action.moveToElement(saving).click().perform();
```

Comment: is it working for you?
It is not working for me is behaviour browser dependent also? i am using Chrome v51.

Comment: can u first try with Firefox?

Comment: Thanks i think it is browser compatibility issue because the same script worked on my friends machine..

Comment: can u tell me which browser, version and selenium-java version are u using..i can try to get suitable comb. for the same

Comment: I am using Chrome v51. I tried the code on my friends lappy in firefox and it worked. Thanks for the concern..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `perform()` on the `click()`

```
action.moveToElement(prod).moveToElement(account).moveToElement(saving).click().perform();
```

You can also try WebElement click

```
action.moveToElement(prod).moveToElement(account).moveToElement(saving).perform();
saving.click();
```

Comment: is it working for you?
It is not working for me is behaviour browser dependent also? i am using Chrome v51.

Comment: @SahilSehgal This is how I usually use it. You can also try "regular" click after the `moveToElement` (see edited answer).

Comment: @SahilSehgal And yes, sometimes Selenium doesn't interact well with new browsers. You can try downgrade the browsers, but it not necessarily the problem.

Comment: Thanks i think it is browser compatibility issue because the same script worked on my friends machine..